# Filter Search query in Spring Mongo DB

Tags: spring, mongodb

In feed collection "likeCount" and "commentCount" are two column. I want to get all document where "likeCount" + "commentCount" greater than 100. How can I write the search filter query in Spring Mongo DB?

Below is my sample feed collection data.

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("55deb33dcb9be727e8356289"),
"channelName" : "Facebook",
"likeCount" : 2,
"commentCount" : 10,
}
```

For compare single field we can write search query like  :

```
BasicDBObject searchFilter = new BasicDBObject();
searchFilter.append("likeCount", new BasicDBObject("$gte",100));

DBCursor feedCursor = mongoTemplate.getCollection("feed").find(searchFilter);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

db.collection.aggregate([{$project:{total:{'$add':["$likeCount","$commentCount"]}}},{$match:{total:{$gt:100}}}])

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use the **[MongoDB Aggregation Framework](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/1.3.0.RC1/reference/html/mongo.core.html#mongo.aggregation.examples)** with Spring Data MongoDB. In Spring Data the following returns all feeds with a combined likes and comments counts greater than 100, using the aggregation framework. :

**Entities**

```
class FeedsCount {

    @Id String id;

    String channelName;

    long likeCount;

    long commentCount;

    long totalLikesComments;

    //...
}
```

**Aggregation**

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(Feed.class, 
    project("id", "channelName", "likeCount", "commentCount")
        .andExpression("likeCount + commentCount").as("totalLikesComments"),        
    match(where("totalLikesComments").gt(100))      
);


//Convert the aggregation result into a List
AggregationResults<FeedsCount> groupResults 
    = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, FeedsCount.class);

List<FeedsCount> results = groupResults.getMappedResults();
```

- In the code above, first create a new aggregation via the **[`newAggregation`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/mongodb/core/aggregation/Aggregation.html)** static factory method to which you pass a list of aggregation operations. These aggregate operations define the aggregation pipeline of your Aggregation.
- As a first step, select the `"id"`, `"channelName"`, `"likeCount"`, `"commentCount"` fields from the input collection with the project operation and add a new field `"totalLikesComments"` which is a computed property that stores the sum of the `"likeCount"` and `"commentCount"` fields.
- Finally in the second step, filter the intermediate result by using a match operation which accepts a Criteria query as an argument.
- Note that you derive the name of the input-collection from the Feed-class passed as first parameter to the newAggregation-Method.